# Running custom protoc-plugin on linux causes

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am building a custom protoc-compiler that is based on googles c++ libraries for protobuf.
I ran into a strange error when running it on linux, while it runs fine on MacOS

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
what():  Unknown error -1
```

After setting up and trying around with my debugger this is the stacktrace:

```
#1  0x00007f61c097b897 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f61c0d1381d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
#3  0x00007f61c0d204da in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
#4  0x00007f61c0d20537 in std::terminate () at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:57
#5  0x00007f61c0d2078e in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=obj@entry=0x5568aec89df0, tinfo=tinfo@entry=0x7f61c0e5a750 <typeinfo for std::system_error>, dest=dest@entry=0x7f61c0d4cc60 <std::system_error::~system_error()>) at /build/gcc/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:95
#6  0x00007f61c0d167ff in std::__throw_system_error (__i=-1) at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/new_allocator.h:89
#7  0x00007f61c14b5c63 in std::call_once<void (&)(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*), google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*&> (__f=@0x7f61c14c0780: {void (const google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable *)} 0x7f61c14c0780 <google::protobuf::(anonymous namespace)::AssignDescriptorsImpl(google::protobuf::internal::DescriptorTable const*)>, __once=...) at /usr/include/c++/7/mutex:698
#8  google::protobuf::internal::AssignDescriptors (table=<optimized out>, table@entry=0x7f61c17dddc0 <descriptor_table_google_2fprotobuf_2fdescriptor_2eproto>) at google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc:2407
#9  0x00007f61c148f440 in google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::GetMetadataStatic () at ./google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.h:623
#10 google::protobuf::FileDescriptorProto::GetMetadata (this=<optimized out>) at google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc:2281
#11 0x00005568acbb22ed in google::protobuf::Message::GetReflection (this=0x7ffd47e4efc0) at /home/leo/CLionProjects/protoc-gen-java-leo/protoc/include/google/protobuf/message.h:333
#12 0x00005568acbad61f in google::protobuf::compiler::java_leo::(anonymous namespace)::CollectExtensions (message=..., extensions=0x7ffd47e4eef0) at /home/leo/CLionProjects/protoc-gen-java-leo/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java_leo/java_file.cc:84
#13 0x00005568acbad8ca in google::protobuf::compiler::java_leo::(anonymous namespace)::CollectExtensions (file_proto=..., alternate_pool=..., extensions=0x7ffd47e4eef0, file_data="\n\021addressbook.proto\022\btutorial\032\037google/protobuf/timestamp.proto\032\roptions.proto\"\255\002\n\006Person\022\"\n\002id\030\001 \001(\tB\022\222\202\031\016java.util.UUIDR\002id\022\022\n\004name\030\002 \001(\tR\004name\022\020\n\003age\030\003 \001(\005R\003age\022\024\n\005email\030\004 \001(\tR\005email\022\064\n\006phones\030\005 \003(\v2\034.tutorial.Person.PhoneNumberR\006phones\022=\n\flast_updated\030\006 \001(\v2\032.google.protobuf.TimestampR\vlastUpdated\032N\n\vPhoneNumber\022\026\n\006number\030\001 \001(\tR\006number\022'\n\004type\030\002 \001(\016\062\023.tutorial.PhoneTypeR\004type\"7\n\vAddressBook\022(\n\006people\030\001 \003(\v2\020.tutorial.PersonR\006people*+\n\tPhoneType\022\n\n\006MOBILE\020\000\022\b\n\004HOME\020\001\022\b\n\004WORK\020\002B+\n\024com.example.tutorialB\021AddressBookProtosP\001b\006proto3") at /home/leo/CLionProjects/protoc-gen-java-leo/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java_leo/java_file.cc:122
#14 0x00005568acbaf23f in google::protobuf::compiler::java_leo::FileGenerator::GenerateDescriptorInitializationCodeForImmutable (this=0x5568aec7d590, printer=0x7ffd47e4f380) at /home/leo/CLionProjects/protoc-gen-java-leo/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java_leo/java_file.cc:439
#15 0x00005568acbaed2a in google::protobuf::compiler::java_leo::FileGenerator::Generate (this=0x5568aec7d590, printer=0x7ffd47e4f380) at /home/leo/CLionProjects/protoc-gen-java-leo/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java_leo/java_file.cc:351
#16 0x00005568acbb73ea in google::protobuf::compiler::java_leo::JavaGenerator::Generate (this=0x7ffd47e4f788, file=0x5568aec77500, parameter="", context=0x7ffd47e4f5f0, error=0x7ffd47e4f5d0) at /home/leo/CLionProjects/protoc-gen-java-leo/src/google/protobuf/compiler/java_leo/java_generator.cc:158
#17 0x00007f61c0f06fae in google::protobuf::compiler::CodeGenerator::GenerateAll (this=0x7ffd47e4f788, files=std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {...}, parameter="", generator_context=0x7ffd47e4f5f0, error=0x7ffd47e4f5d0) at google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.cc:58
#18 0x00007f61c0f16733 in google::protobuf::compiler::GenerateCode (request=..., generator=..., response=response@entry=0x7ffd47e4f6a0, error_msg=error_msg@entry=0x7ffd47e4f680) at google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc:133
#19 0x00007f61c0f16b17 in google::protobuf::compiler::PluginMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7ffd47e4f8c8, generator=0x7ffd47e4f788) at google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc:169
#20 0x00005568acbe9ed5 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffd47e4f8c8) at /home/leo/CLionProjects/protoc-gen-java-leo/main.cpp:10
#21 0x00007f61c097d153 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#22 0x00005568acb9598e in _start ()
```

Since I'm a total C++ noob, it took me around 8 hours trying stuff out and googleing around before I found out the reason, so I wanted to share it here for the next person that might run into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that the "pthread"-library is required and it crashes while calling the "call_once"-method if it's not present. A better error-message would have been great, "what():  Unknown error -1" didn't help out a lot :D

All I did was to add this line in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} pthread)
```

Now it runs like a  charm :)

Hope this helps someone.